# Seeking English burial/death record prior to 1837?

Tags: 19th-century, death-records, burial-records, herefordshire

I'm looking for a burial/death record for a woman that I only have her married name for. I also can't find a birth or marriage record.

Her name is Hannah Evans, born in Leominster,  Herefordshire, England.

I found her husband's baptism/birth date, but not her burial/death, marriage or baptism/birth dates and have been searching relentlessly.

Comment: What is her husband's name, and baptism date and place?  When and where were their children born/baptized? Is there a census record (or something else) that informed you that she was born at Leominster?  Presumably it would also have given an approximate year?

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE!  Please look at the material in the [help] to learn about how the site works, especially [How do I ask a good question?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) -- if we understand what research effort you have made already, we can write better answers for you.

Comment: Have you tried looking at her gravestone? That might have her maiden name, birthdate and death date on it. Good luck in your search!

Answer (score 2):

On the limited information provided the following would appear to be a candidate burial for Hannah Evans on 12 Jan 1824 at Leominster.

> "England Deaths and Burials, 1538-1991," database, FamilySearch
>   (https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:J874-161 : 24 December 2014),
>   Hannah Evans, 12 Jan 1824; citing , reference item 2 p 119; FHL
>   microfilm 1,593,747.